# Adding text string to UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios

I can't pass data from ivar to programmatically create UITextField. Here is what I currently have:

*You'll notice here I'm using the notification center*

```
self.ivar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"DO"]];
NSlog(@"%@", self.ivar); // It is OK Correctly display the string from self.ivar?
```

a different method in the same file

```
self.button.text = self.ivar;
```

The code above doesn't show the content of self.ivar. However, if I write:

```
self.button.text = @"some text";
```

It is ok and some text is displayed in the textfield.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you verify that self.button.text = self.ivar is called after it is assigned?

Comment: are you getting notification before running `self.button.text = self.ivar;` code???

Comment: Actually I get notification after self.button.text = self.ivar. the button is created in loadview method. How to fix that ?

Comment: with the above piece of code no one can fix anything...

Answer (score 0):

Can you do like this in the notification method so that your button text is set there

```
self.ivar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"DO"]];
NSlog(@"%@", self.ivar); // It is OK Correctly display the string from self.ivar
self.button.text = self.ivar;
```